# Convert Times in R

Tags: r, graph, statistics

Hi I cannot seem to convert my time in a CSV file to a readable format in R.

The time format in the CSV file is as follows :

```
"Mon Oct 19 17:26:18 EDT 2015"
```

I need it to convert to something that is readable in R.

I used the following script to convert it but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Time <- strptime(csv.data$Time,format="%m/%d/%Y  %R")  # %R is equiv to %H:%M
Time <- strptime(csv.data$Time,format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:$M")
```

Can someone give me any advice on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The `format` string needs to correspond to the string you have, including position and spaces. If you read the help file for `strptime`, there is an example very close to what you have near the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works, once you get rid of the timezone portion in the original data:

```
s <- 'Mon Oct 19 17:26:18 2015'
t <- strptime(s, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

Output as follows:

```
t
[1] "2015-10-19 17:26:18 EDT"
```

You can do that with:

```
s <- 'Mon Oct 19 17:26:18 EDT 2015'
gsub('EDT', '', s)
```

EXAMPLE code like above with data frames:

```
df <- data.frame(s = rep(format(Sys.time(), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'), 10))
df
                              s
1  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
2  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
3  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
4  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
5  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
6  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
7  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
8  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
9  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016
10 Thu Apr 07 11:33:50 EDT 2016

df$s <- gsub('EDT', '', df$s)
df
                           s
1  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
2  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
3  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
4  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
5  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
6  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
7  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
8  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
9  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016
10 Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016

df$t <- strptime(df$s, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
df
                           s                   t
1  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
2  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
3  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
4  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
5  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
6  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
7  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
8  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
9  Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50
10 Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016 2016-04-07 11:33:50

str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ s: chr  "Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016" "Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016" "Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016" "Thu Apr 07 11:33:50  2016" ...
 $ t: POSIXlt, format: "2016-04-07 11:33:50" "2016-04-07 11:33:50" "2016-04-07 11:33:50" ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer, but I dont understand what the [1] does and R is showing it to me as an error with the following : "Unexpected Token". Can you please provide me additional help about this problem. Thanks!

Comment: That is just the output. :)

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Thanks and sorry I am a complete noob at R.

Comment: Quick inquiry, if I am passing a whole CSV file into the time formal do I just replace the s with csv.data since csv.data is where i have my csv data stored?

Comment: You can do everything above in a vectorized way on a data frame you read from a csv file. Just substitute `s` with `df$s` assuming your data frame is `df` and your column name where those time strings are stored is `s`. Of course, you can name them whatever you want. Make sure to modify the code above to match your own names.

Comment: I added a bunch of stuff to show the same thing working on a data frame. I obviously had to create my own sample data frame since none was provided in the question. But, hopefully it will give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Ok that does help tremendously. I apologize for being so dumb about this. But if I had a said csv file, and the dates along with a bunch of other data was stored in the csv.data variable, would I just once again make a data frame follow the format above?

Comment: Yes, you read the csv into a data frame and then use the code above by just feeding the data column. Rest of the columns in the data frame will be intact.